# Non linear Editor in Blender 3.2 is not playing animations on different tracks

Tags: animation, dopesheet, nla-editor

I ran into a strange problem.

Usually if you have in the NLA Editor more than one track, and you chain these animations one after another on the timeline, they will play in that order.

You need to arrange them that way, so you can blend between them.

This all worked well in the past, but all of a sudden Blender won't play any animation which is not on the top track (even if the top track strip is not overlapping the lower on). It only plays animations which are on the same layer.

[image]

Did they change something? Did I miss something? Is this a bug?

Comment: Hello and Welcome. Would you attach your blender file? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you. And thanks for reminding me. That's a good idea :) But how do I do it here? It's my first post in this forum

Comment: Copy-paste the link to your question, and upload it from here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. And done.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RPLMPQVE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RPLMPQVE/)

Answer (score 1):

Change *Extrapolation* option to *Nothing* in the Strip menu.

Comment: Hi,

man, that really worked! Thanks!

For any other readers. In the NLA Editor (before (!) pushing the animations down from the Dope sheet to the NLA Editor) you have to press "N" and choose under "Edited Action" -> "Extrapolation" ->"Nothing" from the drop down menu.

Comment: This is editable from the 'Strip' tab on the sidebar of the NLA window. You can find the setting under the 'Active Strip' foldout.